# How to read father and assign his id to childs from txt file to database?

Tags: php, xampp

So there is my table example how it looks:

```
ID, Father, Text
1, 0, Text
2, 1, Text1
3, 1, Text2
4, 1, Text3
5, 1, Text4
6, 2, Text5
7, 2, Text6
```

My txt file example:

```
Text3
 name1
 name2
 name3....
```

Only first line is father from database and it needs to pass its id to childs in all other lines. (my table is 300rows and files are less then 1000rows) and childs can't be fathers.

What i want is, when i insert txt file to database get this result:

```
ID, Father, Text
1, 0, Text
2, 1, Text1
3, 1, Text2
4, 1, Text3
5, 1, Text4
6, 2, Text5
7, 2, Text6
8, 4, name1
9, 4, name2
10, 4, name3...
```

Is there any way how to achieve that? I read a bit about nested sets, but still no idea how i can do this.

Now i have entered fathers to all children in text file so that kinda works for now, until i figure  how to do without entering them to txt file.

Comment: You asked that same question here already, https://stackoverflow.com/q/45233119/1427878 Please go read [ask]. The minimum that is expected from you when you ask here, is that you describe what you have done so far to solve the problem.

Comment: Well my question got closed, i was looking at tree structure, nodes, but still cant figure how to do this.

Comment: _“Well my question got closed”_ - aha, and so you just go, _“whatever, I’ll just post the exact same thing again”_ …? _At least_ you should include what you have tried so far, after you got hints from people on your other question.

Comment: NO, i needed to make my question more clear, but no one reopened when i edited it, and it got closed. I didint tried any coding because im stuck, i was looking, reading quite a bit, but cant find some good examples for this

Comment: And how exactly is your question that you just re-posted here any clearer than your original now? This is pretty much the exact same thing as you asked originally, even before you made any edits to the first question. Plus, it is still basically an “I have: ... I want: ...” question - not fit for StackOverflow, unless you can show us what you tried, and be specific as to what the problem is. If your skills don’t allow for that - then you should go hire a developer.

Comment: Well you dont have to help me if you dont want to i know im not good at this. If i will not solve this in a week i will close, delete this.

Comment: How big is the text file? How big is the table? How often are you doing this? With your text file how do you know which lines refer to a parent to get the id, and which lines refer to a child record to use that id? Will the text file contain new child records that can themselves be parents of further child records in the same text file?

Comment: Text files have less then 1000 rows, table is 300rows. In my text file i named first line father (wich is in database already with specific id wich i want to pass to child), rest are children and they cant be fathers.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Given the comment on the data, then something like this (not tested).

Open file. Read the first record and look up the ID to go with it. The read through the rest of the file inserting the rows with the parent id you have already found

```
<?php

$mysqli = new mysqli('host','user','pass','db');
$fp = fopen("some_file.txt", "r");

if (($in_line = fgets($fp, 4096)) !== false) 
{
    $father = trim($in_line);

    if ($result = $mysqli->query("SELECT id FROM some_table WHERE `Text` = '".$mysqli->real_escape_string($father)."'", MYSQLI_USE_RESULT)) 
    {
        if ($row = $result->fetch_object())
        {
            $father_id = (int)$row['id'];
            while (($in_line = fgets($fp, 4096)) !== false) 
            {
                $child = trim($in_line);
                if (!$mysqli->query("INSERT INTO some_table (ID, Father, Text) VALUES(NULL, $father_id, '".$mysqli->real_escape_string($child)."')"))
                {
                    echo "Insert failed";
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
fclose($fp);
```

You can improve the performance of this (eg, you can do many inserts in 1 statement), and this won't cope reliably if the parent name is non unique.

Your current structure is not a nested set model. Setting up a nested set model is more difficult and inserting records into it a bit of a pain, but it does make getting details out easier.

Comment: Hmmm, keep getting error insert failed for all lines

Comment: Can't debug it here. As it is getting there it is doing the first select so suggests the db connection is OK. So probably the statement (at a guess the column name of Text should be escaped with back tics, but I avoid any column name that could be a reserved word).

Comment: Yeah i back ticed table and column names still get same error :D urgh. But thanks for the code this should work after i fix this error.

Comment: Ok now i dont get any error , but file doesnt upload to database

Comment: Echo out the insert statement each time and check it